# Changing fields updates livewire @entangle field

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a component that is entangling a livewire property.

```
<div x-data="{show: @entangle($attributes->wire('model'))}>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.defer="story.show_name" name="show_name" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I have a form within this component. If I update any field within the form it will send an update to the server bug it also modifies the wire:model. An example would be a checkbox. If I uncheck it then the component hides.

Example:

```
[
  {
    "type": "syncInput",
    "payload": {
      "name": "story.show_name",
      "value": false
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "syncInput",
    "payload": {
      "name": "show",
      "value": false
    }
  }
]
```

Any idea why this would suddenly be capturing all input/change events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to me adding all attributes to the component like so `{{$attributes}}`. This would add `wire:model="show"` to the element. Since my component wasn't an input field and just a div it would then accept all `input` events.

I replaced `{{$attributes}}` with `{{$attributes->except('wire:model')}}` to fix the problem.

Comment: You are my hero! I have been searching for hours...